# how to display model attribute in jsp using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Actually my application have Spring MVC...

I have User.jsp, In this i'm creating some empty form (text boxes, textarea..) I'm Display the form using below method In my Controller class. Below code for add empty form on Front end jsp.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String user(Model model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserForm());

    return "profile/user";
}
```

Now i'm getting UserForm in Database(3 rows).

So .. How to add Model attribute,if we add this one is their any override of model attribute?

How to display this model attribute into Jsp using JSTL?

Please suggest me i'm stuck this point..

Comment: You can access in jsp like ${userForm.someField}

Comment: above code gives empty form, But how to add one more model attribute for same form?

Answer (score 16):

Sample Code

```
class UserForm {
    private String name;
    private String address;

    //setter and getter

}
```

In Your Controller

```
 @RequestMapper(value="/user")
    public ModelAndView user(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userForm") ;
        List<UserForm> userForms = yourDatabaseCall();
        mav.addObject("userForms", userForms);  
        return mav;``
    }
```

in jsp page:

```
<c:forEach items="${userForms}" var="userForm">     
   <c:out value="${userForm.name}"/>
   <c:out value="${userForm.address}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hear i'm adding two times and it have overriding(first one is display empty form purpose second one is database data)

Comment: Two times the request goes to same method in controller..If the List is empty , the display show empty form. Otherwise form contain data

Comment: Correct.. it is showing.. but database have two values so form also display in the page two times.. is it correct or not? if it is correct my page have only one form.

Comment: Why dont u use table? Dynamic situation like this we normally use tables or div.. jstl foreach is inside table and outside tr .For each row in List a new row is created in jsp

Answer (score 14):

You can add list of userFomrs as  a model attribute

```
List<UserForm> userForms = yourDatabaseCall();
model.addAttribute("userForms", userForms);
```

In JSTL you can iterate over it

```
<c:forEach items="${userForms}" var="userForm">     
   // Do something
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @NarasimhaKoppadi: Try the suggested way and come back if you get any particular error.