# assigning model attribute to java variable in jsp Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model, jstl, jsp-tags

I want to assign model object to java variable in jsp page for spring mvc application. Can you please help me on how to do that. Like,
I am sending below variable to view

```
model.addAttribute("inCount", 15);
```

Then i want something like below,

```
<%  int rowCount = inCount;
%>
```

May be in jstl, there is a way on writing this kind of java code. Can you please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758877/how-to-display-model-attribute-in-jsp-using-spring-mvc looks relevant here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
int rowcount = (int) request.getAttribute("inCount");
                        **OR**
int rowcount = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("inCount"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the value of the variable 'inCount' you can use c:out

So if you write :

```
<c:out value="${inCount}"/>
```

it will show the value of 'inCount'.

Otherwise, if what you want is to reassign the variable inCount of your scope to a new variable you should use c:set

```
<c:set var="rowCount" scope="session" value="${inCount}"/>
```

You can have more info in:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm

Comment: Thank you all for your advises. Thank you very much