# How to make a Model attribute global?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm using `Spring MVC Framework` and I'd like all the `.jsp` pages of the View to have access to the User's attributes(name, sex, age...). So far, I use the `addAttribute` method of the `Model(UI)` in every Controller to pass the current User's attributes to the `View`. Is there a way to do this only once and avoid having the same code in every `Controller`?

Comment: Take a look in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360784/add-attributes-to-the-model-of-all-controllers-in-spring-3

Comment: If I do as it says then how would I access the Model attibute?

Comment: then try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758877/how-to-display-model-attribute-in-jsp-using-spring-mvc

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use Spring's `@ControllerAdvice` annotation on a new Controller class like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public List<Exercice> populateUser() {
        User user = /* Get your user from service or security context or elsewhere */;
        return user;
    }
}
```

The `populateUser` method will be executed on every request and since it has a `@ModelAttribute` annotation, the result of the method (the `User` object) will be put into the model for every request through the `user` name, it declared on the `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

Theefore the user will be available in your jsp using `${user}` since that was the name given to the `@ModelAttribute` (example: `@ModelAttribute("fooBar")` -> `${fooBar}` )

You can pass some arguments to the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to specify which controllers are advised by this Global controller. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes={FooController.class,BarController.class})
```

or

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages={"foo.bar.web.admin","foo.bar.web.management"}))
```

Comment: How will I access the User's attributes in the jsp?

Comment: What if I want to make a ModelAttribute available only on a collection of jsp pages?

Comment: The @controllerAdvice annotation can be parametrised to target specific controllers

Comment: How to acsses to the variable user from other controllers ?

Answer (score 1):

If it is about User's attributes, you can bind the model bean to session as an attribute which can be accessed on every view. This needs to be done only once.

Another option could be is to implement a HandlerInterceptor, and expose the model to every request.