# Spring boot with HTML table data not populated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I used Spring boot application to populate html table. But table data is not getting populated. Data Mapped `@RequestMapping` not called. I am not able to find the issue. Here is my code..

1. My table code is below

   ```
    <table class="table"  id="myTableId" dt:table="true">
           <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr th:each="user :${users}">
               <td th:text="${user.firstname}">${user.firstname}</td>
               <td th:text="${user.lastname}">${user.firstname}</td>                                   
             </tr>
           </tbody>
    </table>
   ```
2. Here is my controller code

   ```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

     @Controller
      public class UserRightsController {    

              @Autowired
              public CodMasDao dao;

        @RequestMapping(value = {"/user"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public String table(Model md) {       
         List<UserInfoModel> UserInfoModel =dao.getUserInfos();
         md.addAttribute("users", UserInfoModel);
         return "user";
       }
    }
   ```

Please help me.

Comment: Could you share the code of the controller?

Comment: @wargre "/user" mapping not called. why i don't know

Comment: @Juan Bermudez  controller code already given

Comment: Yes, but I would like to see the annotations that you are using in your controller.
Also, try changing the @RequestMapping with @GetMapping("/user")

Comment: @Jaun Bermudez  i have used  ==> import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

Comment: @Jaun Bermdez ==>import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

Comment: @wargre ==>import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

Comment: @Jaun Bermdez  i have updated code

Comment: @wargre I have updated code

Comment: No log on server start (should read /user endpoint validated), no log when calling /user (like invalid content type) ?

Comment: @wargre i did not find any log when server start..

Comment: Your controller class is a subpackage of the main package (the one where main class is ? )

Comment: @wargre my main pakage is ==> package com.app.Application & My controller ==>package com.app.controller.UserRightsController;

Comment: may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697296/inserting-mysql-database-data-into-a-html-form

Comment: That "Model md" parameter looks problematic -- quite possible Spring doesn't have an argument for that parameter and therefore skips the method.  I'd also guess you'd want to return a ModelAndView instead of a String.