# how to keep modelattribute value in jsp?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a jsp page named product.jsp. onload jsp page , I need to populate many drop down list & others. But  it submit form  wheather it is successful or unsuccessful, it clear all textfield. 
 I want to keep the value until i clear. Here is the process which i used.When i submit it redirect same page but modelattribute value is become null. I want keep modelattribute value

1. Jsp page

   ```
   <form:form method="POST" action="/productSetup/add" modelAttribute="productForm">
     <spring:bind path="name">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"   value="${productForm.name}" />              
   </spring:bind>
   ```
2. Here is the controller..

   ```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/productSetup")
    public class ProductController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView index(Model model) {

       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("product");    
       model.addAttribute("getCategoryList", dao.getCategoryList());        
       model.addAttribute("productForm", new ProductModel());

       return modelAndView;
     }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView usrReg(@ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductModel productModel, Errors error, Model model,
   HttpSession session,RedirectAttributes redir,BindingResult result) {        

      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("product");

      redir.addFlashAttribute("productForm", productModel); 

      return new ModelAndView("redirect:/productSetup");

     }

   }
   ```

   Please help me

Comment: post your entire `<form></form>` code from the jsp.
also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697296/inserting-mysql-database-data-into-a-html-form/51697528#51697528 for more info/direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting your form and redirects it to a get.
The problem is that you are always creating a new model attribute:

```
model.addAttribute("productForm", new ProductModel());
```

you should check if the RedirectAttributes contains "productForm" and add it.

```
Object productForm = redirectAttributes.getFlashAttributes().get("productForm");
if(productForm == null){
     productForm = new ProductModel();
}
model.addAttribute("productForm", productForm);
```

This will work only on the first redirect, a second access will not contain the attribute. If you want to keep the data between consecutive get request, you should save it in the session.
   In your post method you can replace

```
redir.addFlashAttribute("productForm", productModel);
```

with :

```
session.setAttribute("productForm", productModel);
```

and in your get request

```
Object productForm = session.getAttribute("productForm");
if(productForm == null || !(productForm instanceOf ProductModel)){
     productForm = new ProductModel();
}
model.addAttribute("productForm", productForm);
```